# Ignore -- comments of sql in php when reading a sql file in php

Tags: php, sql

I have a sql file like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sessionT` (
  `id` int(9) NOT NULL default '0',
  `time` varchar(14) NOT NULL default '',
  `id_session` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
  `token` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id_session`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

so I want to echo all sql statements, however if the sql file has a **--** comment it is not working

```
$f = fopen($SQL_FILE,"r+");
$sql = fread($f, filesize($SQL_FILE));
$sqlArray = explode(';',$sql);
foreach ($sqlArray as $stmt) {
  //add logic to ignire -- comments,...
  if (strlen($stmt)>3 && substr(ltrim($stmt),0,2)!='/*') {
    echo $stmt;
  }
}
```

how to ignore comments in a file like:

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------
-- comment, relation etc
-- Estructure .
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sessionT` (
  `id` int(9) NOT NULL default '0',
  `time` varchar(14) NOT NULL default '',
  `id_session` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
  `token` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id_session`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt the problem is this easy but maybe this will help:

```
if (strlen($stmt)>3 && (substr(ltrim($stmt),0,2)!='/*') || substr(ltrim($stmt),0,3)!='-- ')){
echo $stmt;
}
```

Comment: This would work for /* Single line comments */ But what about multiline comments ?

Answer (score 0):

solution from http://www.frihost.com/forums/vt-8194.html)

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '5120M');
set_time_limit ( 0 );
/***************************************************************************
*                             sql_parse.php
*                              -------------------
*     begin                : Thu May 31, 2001
*     copyright            : (C) 2001 The phpBB Group
*     email                : support@phpbb.com
*
*     $Id: sql_parse.php,v 1.8 2002/03/18 23:53:12 psotfx Exp $
*
****************************************************************************/

/***************************************************************************
 *
 *   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 *   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 *   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
 *   (at your option) any later version.
 *
 ***************************************************************************/

/***************************************************************************
*
*   These functions are mainly for use in the db_utilities under the admin
*   however in order to make these functions available elsewhere, specifically
*   in the installation phase of phpBB I have seperated out a couple of
*   functions into this file.  JLH
*
\***************************************************************************/

//
// remove_comments will strip the sql comment lines out of an uploaded sql file
// specifically for mssql and postgres type files in the install....
//
function remove_comments(&$output)
{
   $lines = explode("\n", $output);
   $output = "";

   // try to keep mem. use down
   $linecount = count($lines);

   $in_comment = false;
   for($i = 0; $i < $linecount; $i++)
   {
      if( preg_match("/^\/\*/", preg_quote($lines[$i])) )
      {
         $in_comment = true;
      }

      if( !$in_comment )
      {
         $output .= $lines[$i] . "\n";
      }

      if( preg_match("/\*\/$/", preg_quote($lines[$i])) )
      {
         $in_comment = false;
      }
   }

   unset($lines);
   return $output;
}

//
// remove_remarks will strip the sql comment lines out of an uploaded sql file
//
function remove_remarks($sql)
{
   $lines = explode("\n", $sql);

   // try to keep mem. use down
   $sql = "";

   $linecount = count($lines);
   $output = "";

   for ($i = 0; $i < $linecount; $i++)
   {
      if (($i != ($linecount - 1)) || (strlen($lines[$i]) > 0))
      {
         if (isset($lines[$i][0]) && $lines[$i][0] != "#")
         {
            $output .= $lines[$i] . "\n";
         }
         else
         {
            $output .= "\n";
         }
         // Trading a bit of speed for lower mem. use here.
         $lines[$i] = "";
      }
   }

   return $output;

}

//
// split_sql_file will split an uploaded sql file into single sql statements.
// Note: expects trim() to have already been run on $sql.
//
function split_sql_file($sql, $delimiter)
{
   // Split up our string into "possible" SQL statements.
   $tokens = explode($delimiter, $sql);

   // try to save mem.
   $sql = "";
   $output = array();

   // we don't actually care about the matches preg gives us.
   $matches = array();

   // this is faster than calling count($oktens) every time thru the loop.
   $token_count = count($tokens);
   for ($i = 0; $i < $token_count; $i++)
   {
      // Don't wanna add an empty string as the last thing in the array.
      if (($i != ($token_count - 1)) || (strlen($tokens[$i] > 0)))
      {
         // This is the total number of single quotes in the token.
         $total_quotes = preg_match_all("/'/", $tokens[$i], $matches);
         // Counts single quotes that are preceded by an odd number of backslashes,
         // which means they're escaped quotes.
         $escaped_quotes = preg_match_all("/(?<!\\\\)(\\\\\\\\)*\\\\'/", $tokens[$i], $matches);

         $unescaped_quotes = $total_quotes - $escaped_quotes;

         // If the number of unescaped quotes is even, then the delimiter did NOT occur inside a string literal.
         if (($unescaped_quotes % 2) == 0)
         {
            // It's a complete sql statement.
            $output[] = $tokens[$i];
            // save memory.
            $tokens[$i] = "";
         }
         else
         {
            // incomplete sql statement. keep adding tokens until we have a complete one.
            // $temp will hold what we have so far.
            $temp = $tokens[$i] . $delimiter;
            // save memory..
            $tokens[$i] = "";

            // Do we have a complete statement yet?
            $complete_stmt = false;

            for ($j = $i + 1; (!$complete_stmt && ($j < $token_count)); $j++)
            {
               // This is the total number of single quotes in the token.
               $total_quotes = preg_match_all("/'/", $tokens[$j], $matches);
               // Counts single quotes that are preceded by an odd number of backslashes,
               // which means they're escaped quotes.
               $escaped_quotes = preg_match_all("/(?<!\\\\)(\\\\\\\\)*\\\\'/", $tokens[$j], $matches);

               $unescaped_quotes = $total_quotes - $escaped_quotes;

               if (($unescaped_quotes % 2) == 1)
               {
                  // odd number of unescaped quotes. In combination with the previous incomplete
                  // statement(s), we now have a complete statement. (2 odds always make an even)
                  $output[] = $temp . $tokens[$j];

                  // save memory.
                  $tokens[$j] = "";
                  $temp = "";

                  // exit the loop.
                  $complete_stmt = true;
                  // make sure the outer loop continues at the right point.
                  $i = $j;
               }
               else
               {
                  // even number of unescaped quotes. We still don't have a complete statement.
                  // (1 odd and 1 even always make an odd)
                  $temp .= $tokens[$j] . $delimiter;
                  // save memory.
                  $tokens[$j] = "";
               }

            } // for..
         } // else
      }
   }

   return $output;
}

$dbms_schema = 'yourfile.sql';

$sql_query = @fread(@fopen($dbms_schema, 'r'), @filesize($dbms_schema)) or die('problem ');
$sql_query = remove_remarks($sql_query);
$sql_query = split_sql_file($sql_query, ';');

$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'user';
$pass = 'pass';
$db = 'database_name';

mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die('error connection');
mysql_select_db($db) or die('error database selection');

$i=1;
foreach($sql_query as $sql){
echo $i++;
echo "
";
mysql_query($sql) or die('error in query');
}

?>
```

Comment: does it remove sql comments like -- (double hypens) or ( more than 2hypens)